# Java: how to create 10 cats? when Cat ("cat" + i) = "cat name" not working as in other languages

Tags: java, string, loops

using loop, I can create

```
My cat is: Cat1
...
My cat is: Cat1
```

However, when I tried to use

```
  Cat ("cat"+i) = new Cat("Cat" + i);
```

I'm making mistakes....

So, what is the simplist way to correct my code to produce

```
cat1 ... cat10 cat instances?


public class TestCat{ 
  public static void main(String [] args){ 

 for (int i=1; i<10; i++){     
   //Cat ("cat"+i) = new Cat("Cat 1");
   Cat cat1 = new Cat("Cat 1");  
   System.out.println("My cat is:  " + cat1 ); 
  }
 } 
} 

class Cat{

 static String catName;
 public Cat(String catName){
   this.catName=catName;
 }
 public String toString(){
   return catName;
}
}
```

**Sorry....I should say**

How to create ten 10 Cat instances.....cat1, ...cat2.....because in other languages, I can use "cat"||i = ..., to create different varaibles, I wonder how I could do similar things in Java....

In other words, I want to name the instances I'm going to create by taking the loop information into account.

Comment: Cat("cat"+i) = new Cat(...) 

is not possible because Java does not support dynamically named variables.  That's why others have suggested an array.   Personally I would use a List.

Comment: thank you for suggesting another route!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a collection if you don't know how many cats you'll have.

```
public class TestCat
{ 
  public static void main(String [] args)
  { 

    Cat[] cats = new Cat[10];    
    Vector catsUnlimited = new Vector(10);    
    Cat myCat = null;

    for (int i=1; i<11; i++)
    {     
    myCat = new Cat("Cat" + i); 
      cats[i-1]= myCat; 

      catsUnlimited.addElement(new Cat("Cat" + i));

      System.out.println("My cat is:  " + cats[i-1] ); 
    }

    System.out.println("Known cats");
    for (int x = 0; x < catsUnlimited.size(); x++)
    {        
     System.out.println("Cat #" + (x+1) + ":" +(Cat)catsUnlimited.get(x));
    }    
  } 
}
```

Note: This code produces incorrect results and had me stumped until I looked closer at the Cat class.

```
My cat is:  Cat1
My cat is:  Cat2
My cat is:  Cat3
My cat is:  Cat4
My cat is:  Cat5
My cat is:  Cat6
My cat is:  Cat7
My cat is:  Cat8
My cat is:  Cat9
My cat is:  Cat10
Known cats
Cat #1:Cat10
Cat #2:Cat10
Cat #3:Cat10
Cat #4:Cat10
Cat #5:Cat10
Cat #6:Cat10
Cat #7:Cat10
Cat #8:Cat10
Cat #9:Cat10
Cat #10:Cat10
```

Here was the culprit:

```
public class Cat
{
     static String catName;
```

Remove the `static` and you are golden.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like an academic problem, so I'll approach it as such.  You need to store ten cats somewhere.  One place you can do that is in an array..

```
public class TestCat{ 
  public static void main(String [] args){ 

    Cat[] cats = new Cat[10];

    // Create my cats
    for (int i= 0; i < 10; i++) {     
      cats[i] = new Cat("Cat " + i + 1);  
    }

    // Print them out
    for (Cat aCat : cats) {
      System.out.printLn("My Cat is: " + aCat);
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i=1; i<10; i++){     
   Cat cat = new Cat("Cat" + i);  
   System.out.println("My cat is:  " + cat ); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class TestCat
{ 
  public static void main(String [] args)
  { 

    Cat[] cats = new Cat[10];
    for (int i=1; i<11; i++)
    {     
      cats[i-1]= new Cat("Cat" + i);

      System.out.println("My cat is:  " + cats[i-1] ); 
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: nice!  thank you!  how about if we don't know how many cats we need to create .... but we know at least one?

Answer (score 1):

Lots of answers above so I'll just add that you can't dynamically change variable names in Java, so the bolded part below is a nono:

Cat **("cat"+i)** = new Cat("Cat 1");

Answer (score 0):

You're hardcoding the cat number:

```
Cat cat1 = new Cat("Cat 1");
```

You should change that to:

```
Cat cat1 = new Cat("Cat " + i);
```

Right?

Answer (score 0):

You need an array.

```
  String[] cats = new String[10];

  for(int i = 0; i < cats.length; i++){
     cats[i] = "Cat" + i;
  }
```

This creates and stores the 10 cats.

Then printing is similar:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < cats.length; i++){
     System.out.println("My cat is " + cats[i]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
for (int i=1; i<10; i++){
        Cat cat = new Cat("Cat"+i);
        System.out.println("My cat is:  " + cat );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java does not support dynamically named variables, so you can't create "cat1" through "cat10" with:

```
Cat ("cat"+i) = new Cat("Cat" + i);
```

*(BTW, what language are you coming from?)*

The Java way would be to create an array (as others have suggested).   If you don't know how many instances you will need, you can dynamically size the array:

```
public class TestCat
{
    static class Cat
    {
        private String name;

        Cat(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "Cat{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Cat[] someCats = createCats(10);
        printCats(someCats);

        Cat[] lotsaCats = createCats(42);
        printCats(lotsaCats);
    }

    private static void printCats(Cat[] cats)
    {
        // Print them out
        for (Cat aCat : cats)
        {
            System.out.println("My Cat is: " + aCat);
        }
    }

    private static Cat[] createCats(int ncats)
    {
        Cat[] cats = new Cat[ncats];

        // Create my cats
        for (int i = 0; i < ncats; i++)
        {
            cats[i] = new Cat("Cat " + i + 1);
        }
        return cats;
    }
}
```

You could also use a List instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can create **n** number of Cats :

**Code:**

```
public class TestCat
{

  public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
  {  
      int x=0; 
      DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(System.in);
      x=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
      Cat[] cats = new Cat[x];
      for (int i=1; i<x; i++)
      {     
          cats[i-1]= new Cat("Cat" + i);       
          System.out.println("My cat is:  " + cats[i-1] ); 
      }
   }
}
```